# Name Server / DNS Lookup

Tags: dns, nameserver, dns-servers

What is the difference between a name server lookup and a DNS lookup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing.  "Name Server" is short for "Domain Name Server", which is what "DNS" stands for.

Answer (score 0):

Different places in the world and different people just call it different things.

**Nameserver** aka **Name Server** aka **nameserver DNS** aka **Domain Name Server**

There is *no difference.*